# How to set Slack reminder for last day of every month?

Tags: slack, slack-commands

I need to complete timesheet of work until midnight of every last day of month. Since it's easy to forget, I want to set reminder on say 1PM of the last day. What's the correct syntax to configure it?

All my attempts either don't work or are clumsy:

- `/remind me "Complete timesheet!!!" at 13:00 on the last day of every month` - sets 1st instead and does not completely understand
- `/remind me "Complete timesheet!!!" at 13:00 on the 31st of every month` - works for 31-day-long months, ignores for shorter months
- `/remind me "Complete timesheet!!!" at 13:00 on the 30st of every month` - (I guess) works every month except February, for 30-day-long months one can manually snooze by day
- `/remind me "Complete timesheet!!!" at -11:00 on the 1st of every month` - sets 1st instead and does not completely understand
- `/remind me "Complete timesheet!!!" 11 hours before 1st day of every month` - sets 1st instead and does not completely understand
- 12x copy of `/remind me "Complete timesheet!!!" at 13:00 every November 30th` for literally mentioned last day of every month - works but too lengthy

I will also accept answer with link to any documentation with formalized syntax of `/remind` command (BNF, railroad diagram) from which the possibility of such command would be either provable or disprovable.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1037708/slackbot-how-to-set-a-reminder-for-last-wednesday-of-the-month-or-last-day-of-th

Comment: The official docs has an example that uses the 28th https://slack.com/help/articles/4417526840723-Set-a-monthly-reminder-to-submit-your-expenses so what you (and I) need is probably not possible without making 12 separate reminders.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was adding an entry specific for each month. It is inefficient, but only took a few minutes. For example, for reports due the first Thursday of the month.

/remind #[channel] "Please update your TPS report" on July X at 8am
/remind #[channel] "Please update your TPS report" on August X at 8am